# Pagination on Codeigniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CI,

I have selected a database from table. Now want to create Pagination. The Pagination link showed up. But when I click page 2 the error message is a `404 Page Not Found`. How can I fix that?

This is the script -
**on Controller**

```
function post()
 {

   $table_row_count = $this->db->count_all('post');

   $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/septiyo/index.php/admin/page/';
   $config['total_rows'] = $table_row_count;
   $config['per_page'] = 10;
   $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $this->load->model('admin_model');  
    $data_admin['dataadmin']=$this->admin_model->view_post_model();
    $this->load->view('post_view',$data_admin);


 }//end of funciton
```

**on Model**

```
public function view_post_model()
    {
        $hasil = $this->db->get('post');
        return $hasil->result();

    }//end funciton
```

**on View**

```
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0' align='center' width='600'>
     <tr>
        <th>Judul</th>
        <th>Posting</th>
        <th>Ketegori</th>
        <th>Tanggal</th>
        <th>Aksi</th>
     </tr>";
foreach($dataadmin as $row)
{
    //$this->load->helper('text');
    $post = $row->post;
    $string = word_limiter($post,10);

    echo "<tr>";    
    echo "<td>$row->title</td>";
    //echo "<td>$row->post</td>";
    echo "<td>$string</td>";
    echo "<td>$row->kategori</td>";
    echo "<td>$row->tgl</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo anchor('company_controller/view_edit_employee/'.$row->id, 'Edit')." | ";
    echo anchor('company_controller/confirm_delete_employee/'.$row->id, 'Hapus');
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}    


echo "</table><br>";
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is in the base_url that you set. If the pagination is being showing properly I bet that the problem must be there. Try to change the url manually in the browser if you don't realize what the correct url is.

Comment: Thanks For Your Attention, I have Try manually like you advice to change the URL, but still not work. any idea?

Comment: try to check the value of the variable $offset

Answer (score 0):

```
this may help you.

// On Controller Side

function post(){

   $limit = 10;
   $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);    

   $table_row_count = $this->db->count_all('post');

   $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/septiyo/index.php/admin/page/';

   $config['total_rows'] = $table_row_count;

   $config['per_page'] = $limit;
   $config['uri_segment'] = 3;  
   $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $this->load->model('admin_model');  
    $data_admin['dataadmin']=$this->admin_model->view_post_model($limit,$offset);
    $this->load->view('post_view',$data_admin);


 }//end of funciton


// On Model Side
public function view_post_model($limit, $offset)
    {
    $hasil = $this->db->get('post', $limit , $offset);
        return $hasil->result();

    }//end funciton

what you are doing is something wrong, since to get the result is paginated form you need to  instruct the database to return the result in breaks, and this is what the limit and offset will do for you, please check this once.

I have not checked your view, that you can examine, and also ensure that you are getting the correct uri_segment and also you have ulr helper enabled in config.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function post()
 {
 $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
    if(!$offset)
     $offset=0;

 $table_row_count = $this->db->count_all('post');

 $config['base_url'] = base_url().'admin/page';
```

hope it will help you...